# how to show form questionery after button ok click in confirmation jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to show form questionery after button ok click in confirmation jquery.thanks...

```
$("input[value='Close']").click(function () {
                var ValidComment = document.getElementById('comment_update').value;
                if (ValidComment == '') {
                    $("#ErrorUpdate").text("Comment is Required");                
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return confirm('Are you sure to close this ticket ?'); 
                    --show form here-??               
                }
            });
```

Comment: After you've returned you can't do anything else within the function, since control's been returned, and nothing else within that function will execute.

Comment: take a look at http://api.jquery.com/html/ .hope this helps.

Comment: @raminomrani Why would that be helpful here?

Comment: @Blazemonger because I think Citra's goal is to change html content(in this case,show a form).although Citra's function definition sequence is wrong.html() function will help after redesigning the function algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work, but I can't test it:

```
        $("input[value='Close']").click(function () {

            if ($("#comment_update").val() == '') {
                $("#ErrorUpdate").text("Comment is Required");                
                return false;
            }
            else {
               if (confirm('Are you sure you want to close this ticket?')) {
               //Show form code goes here
               $("#form").show();              
            }
        });
```

Comment: Wrap the whole function in a `$(function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

This would work too

```
$("input[value='Close']").click(function () {
    var ValidComment = document.getElementById('comment_update').value;
    if (ValidComment == '') {
        $("#ErrorUpdate").text("Comment is Required");                
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var result = confirm('Are you sure to close this ticket ?');
        if (result) {
            $("form-here").css("display", "block");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```